# во вкладке project нет папки app

Tags: android, android-studio, git-branch

Исчезла папка `App` в дереве проекта.
Перед этим сделал `git merge` локальных веток в AndroidStudio.
После этого перешел на другую ветку проекта, а там во вкладке `Project` нет app, а только `Gradle Scripts`.

А в окошке выбора запуска проекта `app` перечеркнуто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В редакторе конфигурации запуска такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите где искать проблему.

---

**UPD**:
Обновил вопрос в связи с попытками что-то сделать по советам из комментов и ответов.

Баг какой то избирательный. При переходе на одну ветку открывается нормально все дерево проекта. При переходе на другие папка "App" отсутствует в дереве проекта в режиме отображения "Android".

В режиме отображения дерева "Project" - иногда папки проекта есть после многократных танцев с бубном. Но чаще всего  картина такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что в том проекте с которым вы провели слияние с гита?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko Обычный коммерческий проект. На проекте есть пару веток. Работаю с ним давно. Как обычно после завершения таска делал мердж на мастер ветку. Ипотом пушил на  гит (точнее Bitbucket). Подправлял конфликтные строки если были.

Comment: а если загрузить с вашей системы контроля версий проект и посмотреть что там есть, может там нету этих папок?

Comment: Имеете ввиду pull?

Comment: честно говоря я очень слабо разбираюсь в терминологии системы контроля версий, я имею в виду скачать отдельно проект, не в ваш текущий проект, а создать новый и туда импортировать

Comment: Файлы на удаленном сервере есть. Проверял.

Comment: а попробуйте опять провести слияние с серверным проектом, может была ошибка какая-то

Comment: А вот только что закрыл проект и открыл заново - папки появились.

Comment: а какая у вас версия студии?

Comment: Студия последняя - 3.2

Comment: Измените представление на Project

Comment: Временно обошелся тем что перенес с глюкнутой ветки в новую ветку все файлы с папок  java и res (работать то как то нужно). Но остается еще несколько веток которые еще предстоит фиксить.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сначала `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart` и `Build -> Clean Project`, затем `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: Только после перезагрузки студии появляются папки. Но каждый раз перезагружать студию когда переходишь на другую ветку не решение проблемы.

Comment: Ждите апдейт студии, наверное

Comment: @V.March, а синхронизации тоже не помогают? Наверное у Вас в индекс гита попали какие-то служебные файлы - при чекаутах они перезаписываются и проект рушится.

Comment: @woesss Синхронизации работают как то криво. Иногда появляется папка "App" но в ней структура дерева как в режиме "Project". Та и не все файлы показывает, такое чувство что они рэндомно на каком то этапе крашатся. Правда время от времени и нормализуется структура дерева. Не могу проследить никакой закономерности :(

Answer (score 0):

Я кажется понял в чем у вас была проблема, у самой последней студии есть такой глюк при отображении проекта типом android, я не знаю в чем проблема, но обновление списка файлов либо происходит очень медленно и плохо либо не происходит вообще. Для проверки можно выбрать тип отображения project и там должны быть все ваши файлы.

После обновы теперь есть индикатор обновления списка файлов в верхнем правом углу панели, и пока он "крутится" то ваши файлы будут вероятнее всего не видны. Что лично я делаю для решения этой проблемы: открываю директории поочередно, иногда файлы подгружаются, могу свернуть и развернуть вкладку, могу поменять тип отображения проекта с `android` на `project`, иногда помогает.

Самый рабочий вариант это ждать обновы от гугла, потому-что в предыдущей версии такого не было, а теперь этот косяк появился.

Comment: Файлы есть во вкладке Project но как сделать так чтобы этот список отобразился во вкладке Android?

Comment: это довольно интересная задача))) после обновы я не знаю что они там "пофиксили" но теперь очень сложно сделать так чтобы в вкладке android были все файлы, хотя согласитесь что на этой вкладке намного удобнее просматривать все что есть у вас в проекте. Я сейчас дополню ответ тем способом которым я пользуюсь)

Comment: Скажем так, есть  плюсы и минусы в отображении всех папок. Плюс- ориентируешься что за каша у тебя в проекте. Минус - каша из файлов которые никогда и открывать не придется. А нужный файл имеет такую глубину вложенности что пол-экрана занимает только дерево проекта. До этого юзал  идею чистую - но Студия сделана под нужды андроид-девелоперов - без лишней мишуры.

Comment: К сожалению не всегда есть папка проекта в режиме Project. Какой то глюк видимо не только в студии но и у меня локально. Так как на другую ветку переходит нормально. Уже раз 5 попробовал попрыгать с ветки на ветку. Ветки бажатся избирательно.

Comment: Проект не запускается даже в режиме Project.

Comment: а до обновы все работало?

Comment: Работало и после обновы. Не могу восстановить цепочку  событий которые были до бага. Последнее примечательное - мердж  с большим количеством изменений и пара конфликтных строк (которые пофиксил)

Comment: очень странная ситуация честно говоря)) я погуглю может что-то найду по вашей проблеме